# Do cottages generate more keflings?

Tags: a-kingdom-for-keflings

Does upgrading a house that already has love to a cottage generate any more keflings?  Is there a reason to upgrade houses to cottages if it doesn't generate more keflings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/946839-a-kingdom-for-keflings/46766200):

> The cottage is an upgraded house. You need to add the extra cottage
>   parts next to an existing house. It gets you more points and stars,
>   but no extra Keflings.
>
> If you build all the components of a regular house, plus the two extra
>   parts for a cottage, you can build a whole cottage.  If, instead, you
>   just build the two extra parts, and you've got room between your
>   houses, you should see some squares around the house where you can
>   place the new parts.  Once both are placed, your house automatically
>   upgrades to a cottage.

Comment: The determining factor for how many keflings you get is the type of love you put into a dwelling.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't give you additional keflings, it still allows you to house 2 keflings just like the regular house.

You do get 3 stars and additional points for upgrading to a cottage, that is all. If you're short on resources, don't bother unless you're going for one of the star missions.